# Why does it cause errors in subsubsubsections

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, acmart

I want another level of subsections (i.e. subsubsubsections). For that I am using;

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\paragraph{This is my subsubsubsection}
```

However, this gives me an error saying that `Missing number, treated as zero.`. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}

\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
\acmConference[Woodstock '18]{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection}{June 03--05, 2018}{Woodstock, NY}
\acmBooktitle{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection, June 03--05, 2018, Woodstock, NY}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-9999-9/18/06}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\title{The Name of the Title is Hope}

\author{Ben Trovato}
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\email{trovato@corporation.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin}
\authornotemark[1]
\email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
  \city{Dublin}
  \state{Ohio}
  \postcode{43017-6221}
}

\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, et al.}

\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010562</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Embedded systems</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010575.10010755</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Redundancy</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010554</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Robotics</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10003033.10003083.10003095</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Networks~Network reliability</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Computer systems organization~Embedded systems}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computer systems organization~Redundancy}
\ccsdesc{Computer systems organization~Robotics}
\ccsdesc[100]{Networks~Network reliability}

\keywords{datasets, neural networks, gaze detection, text tagging}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Some Text here
\subsection{mmm}
Some Text here
\subsubsection{mmm}
Some Text here
\paragraph{nnn}
Some Text here
\end{document}
```

I got this template from: https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/submissions

Comment: your code give mi error `\bibfont undefined` ... so your mwe is not complete. please make your mwe shorter (in preamble only add releveant packages and command for`secnumdepth` and in document body only examples of `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection` and `paragraph`.

Comment: @Zarko It looks like the other pages in the zip file are connected with this page. The zip file is in https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/submissions.

Comment: @Zarko Moreover, the `secnumdepth` works fine with other templates such as article, apa6.

Comment: i have installed recent version of `acmart` (acmart-preload-hook.tex) . since i very rarely use `acmart` i now observe, that it seems to be broken or in my instalation are missing some of its supporting files (i use `miktex`). compiling your mwe i get bunch of errors related to bibliography, but forcing compilation i obtain numbered `\paragraph`.  due to this my problems i'm sorry, but i can't help you further. just now i tested your code in overleaf and there it works fine.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks a lot for your comment. I am aslo using overleaf. But it gives me errors. Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `acmart` class doesn't support numbering below the `\subsubsection` level.

You can “fix” the immediate error by supplying

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{r@tocindent4}{0pt}
\@namedef{r@tocindent5}{0pt}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble. The lengths are set to zero, since I don't think you need the table of contents up to that level anyhow.

[image]

Full code.

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}

\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
\acmConference[Woodstock '18]{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection}{June 03--05, 2018}{Woodstock, NY}
\acmBooktitle{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection, June 03--05, 2018, Woodstock, NY}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-9999-9/18/06}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{r@tocindent4}{30pt}
\@namedef{r@tocindent5}{30pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{The Name of the Title is Hope}

\author{Ben Trovato}
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\email{trovato@corporation.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin}
\authornotemark[1]
\email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
  \city{Dublin}
  \state{Ohio}
  \postcode{43017-6221}
}

\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, et al.}

\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010562</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Embedded systems</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010575.10010755</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Redundancy</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010554</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Robotics</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10003033.10003083.10003095</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Networks~Network reliability</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Computer systems organization~Embedded systems}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computer systems organization~Redundancy}
\ccsdesc{Computer systems organization~Robotics}
\ccsdesc[100]{Networks~Network reliability}

\keywords{datasets, neural networks, gaze detection, text tagging}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Some Text here
\subsection{mmm}
Some Text here
\subsubsection{mmm}
Some Text here

\paragraph{nnn}
Some Text here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. How did you type `subsubsubsection`? Is it like `\paragraph{nnn}`? That did not work for me.

Comment: @Emi `\subsubsubsection` is not defined. The sectioning level below `\subsubsection` is `\paragraph`.

Comment: Can you please add the latex code in the answer, because `\paragraph{nnn}` did not work with the fix.

Comment: @Emi Done; but it's essentially the same as yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I have forgotton to add the command `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}`. Thank you once again :)